# cannot center align canvas

Tags: html, canvas, alignment, center

I Have been googling for solutions to no avail. I just want to `center-align` my `canvas`.
I have tried `float="center"`, `text-align="center"`, `margin-top: 100px`
but my stage didnt align center in the browser.
Any help is appreciated.

```
<body onLoad="Main();">
<canvas id="Shooter" width="320" height="480" align="center">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could center align it by:

```
#Shooter {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Make sure the parent container have 100% width.

Here's a pen. 
http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/aNpWoB

Comment: Hi Asim, thanks so much. i tried this and it finally work. can you advise why does  "margin: auto; " makes it work? thanks alot

Comment: @herblackcat. Auto-ing margins will tell the browser to evenly fill the left & right margins by evenly dividing any space not used by the canvas == centering!

Comment: @herblackcat Hope you understand why `margin:auto` works (Thanks markE). If things worked you could always accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you remove the `width`, `height` and `align` tags from canvas. Instead add a style region to your html and define a css-style for canvas:

```
<style>
    canvas {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 320px;
        height: 480px;
    }
</style>
```

Your canvas would look like this:

```
<canvas id="Shooter">
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Käsebrot you should separate your html coding from your css, and open style.css file and connect it to your html page in the 'head' section  link `rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"` and then give your canvas css properties.
To center the canvas you only need the give values to the margin and display attributes.

```css
canvas#Shooter {
    
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
  </head>

  <body onLoad="Main();">
    <canvas id="Shooter">
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Sivan and Kasebrot, thanks alot for your advice. I will practise more