# How do I keep the ellipses in the center when the screen is resized

Tags: c#, wpf

Ive got the following WPF form. Im new to WPF .. how do I keep the ellipses in the center even when resizing? I included the code that scales when resizing

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow" x:Class="SpectrumVisualizer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="369.737" Width="567.487" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeChanged="mainWindow_SizeChanged">
    <DockPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Margin="0,-41,-14,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left">

            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="380">
                <Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="Black" Height="339" Width="499" Canvas.Top="41">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar01"   Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" Margin="19,32,0,0"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar02"  Fill="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,32,0,0" Stroke="Black" Width="295" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar03"  Fill="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="141" Margin="19,107,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar04"  Fill="LimeGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="138,64,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="231"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar05"  Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="194,42,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar06"  Fill="Turquoise" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="67,125,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="363"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar07"  Fill="Cyan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="183" Margin="167,88,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar08"  Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="204,64,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar09"  Fill="Violet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="105,139,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="Bar10"  Fill="Magenta" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="129" Margin="194,119,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
private void mainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCanvas.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
    MyCanvas.Height = e.NewSize.Height;

    double xChange = 1, yChange = 1;

    if (e.PreviousSize.Width != 0)
        xChange = (e.NewSize.Width / e.PreviousSize.Width);

    if (e.PreviousSize.Height != 0)
        yChange = (e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height);



    ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(MyCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M11 * xChange, MyCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M22 * yChange);
    MyCanvas.LayoutTransform = scale;
    MyCanvas.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Center it in its parent.
2. Get rid of all the redundant stuff around it that offsets it. Get rid of your SizeChanged event handler. Use HoriziontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to do the actual centering.

Like so:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
            <!-- 
            Note added right/bottom margin on this Grid. 
            The ellipses already provided a left/top margin. 
            If it were me, I'd have the ellipses aligned at zero top/left, 
            and do all the margins in the Grid. 
            -->
            <Grid Name="MyCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,19,19">

                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar01"  Fill="Red"       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="19,32,0,0"  Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar02"  Fill="Orange"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="105,32,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295"  />
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar03"  Fill="Yellow"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="141" Margin="19,107,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar04"  Fill="LimeGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="138,64,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="231"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar05"  Fill="Green"     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="194,42,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar06"  Fill="Turquoise" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="67,125,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="363"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar07"  Fill="Cyan"      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="183" Margin="167,88,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar08"  Fill="Blue"      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="204,64,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar09"  Fill="Violet"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="105,139,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Bar10"  Fill="Magenta"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="129" Margin="194,119,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: As I mentioned Im very very new to WPF. So Im still trying to figure things out. But the resize function & canvas is there for when I for example maximise the window that the shapes scales accordingly

Comment: Great ! it keeps it centred. I commente out the resize function and the scaling is now obviously gone. Is there a way to scale it in the XAML?

Comment: @Eminem See update. The ViewBox takes over the job you were doing in the SizeChanged handler. `ViewBox` is a wanton beast; it's not intuitively clear how to make it do what you want.

Comment: @Eminem Awesome. I'm really enjoying your graphic, too.

Comment: You should see how it lights up... I do a Fast Fourier Transform on music and the ellipses fade in and out to the beat.... :)  Night clubs are going to get crazy.. all thanks to you! :)

Answer (score -1):

I used centre alignment centre. try that.

See use example in [cannot center align canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055910/cannot-center-align-canvas)